# DateFormat issue when migrated the ASP.net application from windows 2008r2 to windows 2012r2

Tags: asp.net, oracle, datetime

I am having a .Net Application and connected to oracle. In server A - which is having windows server 2008r2 it is running fine and date format is dd-mmm-yyyy , but in server B -which is having windows server 2012r2  the date format is getting changed to yyyy-mm-dd , because of which i am facing issue.

Any solutions/Lead is appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: What is "the issue" you get? Show us the code and related which creates problems.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values, both in [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) and Oracle. If you see strings, it's because your own code converted the dates to strings one way or another. If you see different formats, it's because either the locale is different between the machines, or the code that formats the dates into strings changed

Comment: Another possibility is that the data is stored as a string, not a date in the database, and the code that writes that string has changed. The problem is once again caused because the wrong type (string) is used

Comment: Post your code and table schemas. What are the types of the date columns? How are you querying the database? Finally, how do you inspect the values, where did you see `dd-mmm-yyyy`? Could it be that the only thing that changed is the display format string?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos- Thank you for your response. I have changed the date format in the code and it worked.